# How to find the IP connected with teamviewer?

Tags: ip, teamviewer

I need to know how to find the IP of the pc connected into my pc with teamviewer ???
how can I do??

I tryed with netstat:

netstat -n | find ":6039" | find "ESTABLISHED"

but It doesn't work because It seems not shows the IP of the pc.

How can I do?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way you do this is making use of a firewall program. Often when a program asks for permission to connect to a remote system it will ask for permission and also provide you with the IP and/or hostname of the server in question.

Another way you can do this is with a packet sniffing program such as Wireshark. Basically, by making better use of the inbuilt filtering capabilities you can track a stream of traffic between you and your target (something like 'Track TCP Stream' which tracks a particular line of communications).

https://www.wireshark.org/

Obviously, you've discovered 'netstat'. Looking up details regarding the program indicate potentially different port usage though...

> Which ports are used by TeamViewer?
>
> In general, TeamViewer will always work if surfing on the Internet is possible. Hence, no firewall configuration is required. As an alternative to port 80 HTTP, port 443 HTTPs is also being checked. In addition, it is also possible to open only port 5938 TCP on the outgoing side. Data traffic should then be able to pass through on this port without any problems.

http://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/334-Which-ports-are-used-by-TeamViewer.aspx